# QML ListView currentIndex incorrectly set to 0

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

When I manually change the `currentIndex` of a `ListView`, the  `currentIndex` is set to 0 before being set to the given value.
The main problem is that `onCurrentIndexChanged` is triggered 2 times: with value 0, then with value 2.

See the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 100
    height: 100

    ListView {
        id: list
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: -1
        model: ListModel {}
        delegate: Text {
            text: model.name
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            model.append({"name": "plip"})
            model.append({"name": "plop"})
            model.append({"name": "ploup"})
            currentIndex = 2
        }

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            console.log("currentIndex", currentIndex)
        }

    }
}
```

The logs I obtain:

```
qml: currentIndex 0
qml: currentIndex 2
```

The only solution I found to avoid this problem is to have another property `indexToBeSet` and to compare `indexToBeSet` with the actual `currentIndex`:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 100
    height: 100

    ListView {
        id: list

        property int indexToBeSet: -1

        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: -1
        model: ListModel {}
        delegate: Text {
            text: model.name
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            model.append({"name": "plip"})
            model.append({"name": "plop"})
            model.append({"name": "ploup"})
            setCurrentIndex(2)
        }

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            console.log("currentIndex", currentIndex)
            if (currentIndex === indexToBeSet) {
                console.log("=> do some stuff")
            }

        }

        function setCurrentIndex(index) {
            indexToBeSet = index
            currentIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
qml: currentIndex 0
qml: currentIndex 2
qml: => do some stuff
```

But I think it is a really annoying solution.

Why is it happening? Is it a bug or the expected behavior?
Is there a better way to avoid the problem?

**More details**:

It looks like the problem only happens when I change the `currentIndex` after adding elements when the previous `currentIndex` is equal to `-1`.
See the following code :

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    model.append({"name": ""})
    model.append({"name": ""})
    model.append({"name": ""})
    currentIndex = 1 // WILL BE SET TO 0 BEFORE 1
    model.append({"name": ""})
    currentIndex = 2 // no problem because currentIndex was not -1
    currentIndex = -1 // no problem
    currentIndex = 2 // no problem because we did not add new elements after setting to -1
    currentIndex = -1 // no problem
    model.append({"name": ""})
    currentIndex = 1 // WILL BE SET TO 0 BEFORE 1
}
```

And the corresponding logs:

```
qml: currentIndex 0
qml: currentIndex 1
qml: currentIndex 2
qml: currentIndex -1
qml: currentIndex 2
qml: currentIndex -1
qml: currentIndex 0
qml: currentIndex 1
```

Comment: Not sure myself. I am having trouble with ListView as well. It seems to always reset the index to 0 whenever my model changes.